# How to use the Language Customization on the MOODLE 4.0.2+?

Tags: server, customization, local, moodle, platform

In Moodle Open source learning platform language customization is not working on local server on version of MOODLE 4.0.2+.l

Answer (score 0):

Under the language customization option in the site admin settings, select the language pack and search for the strings.